# Matrix of integers to boolean matrix

Tags: matrices, boolean-algebra

My Question is about converting a matrix of numbers, say each row is an item and each column is a feature of the item. The features are currently integers but I want to convert the feature quantification to boolean (i.e., 0 or 1).

One way I thought to solve this is to get the position of the top 5% per each row (it could be any value really) and if a feature has a value greater than it, the 1, else 0.

But I was wondering if there are other suggestions, perhaps mathematically, to convert rows of features in a matrix to boolean.

-thx

Comment: It'd have to be wholly dependent on what you say as your feature should be classified as. There are simple enough codes to "threshold" a matrix to boolean values but I don't see any "Mathematical" problem here per se.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do the conversion? If you can explain why you want to do such a conversion, then that reason can be used to help figure out a good way to do the conversion.

Comment: Well, I want to compare sets of features (columns) amongst each item (row) and having them being YES/NO for the features, I thought would be a good way to do this; especially as a preliminary step.